# Haskell conversion between types

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion

Again stuck on something probably theoretical. There are many libraries in Haskell, i'd like to use less as possible. If I have a type like this:

```
data Note = Note { _noteID :: Int
                 , _noteTitle :: String
                 , _noteBody :: String
                 , _noteSubmit :: String
                 } deriving Show
```

And use that to create a list of `[Note {noteID=1...}, Note {noteID=2...}, ]` et cetera. I now have a list of type `Note`. Now I want to write it to a file using `writeFile`. Probably it ghc will not allow it considering writeFile has type `FilePath -> String -> IO ()`. But I also want to avoid deconstructing (writeFile) and constructing (readFile) the types all the time, assuming I will not leave the Haskell 'realm'. Is there a way to do that, without using special libs? Again: thanks a lot. Books on Haskell are good, but StackOverflow is the glue between the books and the real world.

Comment: You have a  list of type `[Note]`.

Comment: why not just `writeFile path show [Note {noteID=1...}, Note {noteID=2...}, ]`?

Comment: The question is very broad. You should start with the question "What should the resulting file look like?", then write code to accomplish that.

Comment: so you want an operation of type `FilePath -> [Note] -> IO ()` but you have `FilePath -> String -> IO ()`, and you have a type `[Note]` value? Seems you need to convert that value to `String` type value, thus using a function of type `[Note] -> String`. `show` is one such function.

Comment: @Chepner. True it is broad. What the file looks like does not matter to me so much. The 'higher aim' is to write something to the file that I can read back and use the same way I used to get it there. Show indeed is an option, but it immediately implies read and nested quotes.

Comment: So derive `Read` for your data type, and `read data :: [Note]` should work fine. Nested quotes should not be an issue, unless you need something other than `read` to process it, in which case we are back to "What should the resulting file look like?"

Comment: @Chepner: that did the trick for me. I consider this an answer to the question and did not consider deriving read on my type. Don't want to post it as a completely new question, but can I read it as an 'Either', so I also cover the case of having read exploding?

Comment: Use `readEither` from the `Text.Read` module. `readEither "1.3" :: Either String Int` will return a `Left` value (with the same generic error message that the exception raised by `read` would show), while `readEither "1.3" :: Either String Float` will return a `Right` value.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a "quick fix", for a one-off script or something like that, you can derive `Read` in addition to `Show`, and then you'll be able to use `show` to convert to `String` and `read` to convert back, for example:

```
data D = D { x :: Int, y :: Bool }
    deriving (Show, Read)

d1 = D 42 True

s = show d1
-- s == "D {x = 42, y = True}"

d2 :: D
d2 = read s
-- d2 == d1
```

However, please, *please* don't put this in production code. **First,** you're implicitly relying on how the record is coded, and there are no checks to protect from subtle changes. **Second,** the `read` function is *partial* - that is, it will crash if it can't parse the input. **And finally,** if you persist your data this way, you'll be stuck with this record format and can never change it.

For a production-quality solution, I'm sorry, but you'll have to come up with an explicit, documented serialization format. No way around it - in any language.

Comment: Fyodor, I like to assume all I am trying, I'd like to be able to use in a production file. Will Ness and @assembly.jc also mentioned 'Show', which is a perfect solution for getting stuff in the file, but I would assume to need 'read' for getting it out. Another downside is then having again nested quotes in the file, which I usually dislike if the need exists to parse a file.

Comment: If this is ultimately for production use, then you should absolutely not use any quick fixes. Come up with a format, document it, write functions to convert to and from, then use those. Trust me, long term quick fixes will come back to bit you.

Comment: Note that `readEither` (which I mentioned in the comments) only addresses the second concern listed here.